# How to center bootstrap row elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Good evening at all!
It's been a few days since I'm trying to figure out how to center the contents of a row bootstrap. I'll explain:
The Row consists of 12 columns (as normal for bootstrap). In my layout, I use only 9 (3 elements out of 3). How do I make the excess space be equally divided between the outer margins of my width 3 elements?

I'm trying to modify the bootstrap css code, but obviously I did just damage. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: So you want your row to be
| left margin 1.5 col width | content 9 col width | right margin 1.5 col width | ?

Comment: You can use: `style="margin-left: calc((100% /12) *1.5);"` in the first column.

Comment: add {col-sm-offset-1} on all element

Comment: Use `width: calc(100% / 9)` for the elements in the row. Bootstrap grid system is really great, but sometimes it's easier to to use a calc when using a number of rows that won't equally divide into 12.

Comment: is this bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: And post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="width: 75%; margin: auto;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/fbtw6/1502/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
**CSS**

.row.text-center > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Centered content here
    </div>
</div>
```